# Sending command to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq

I am using WinForms & C# to access a SQL Server 2008 on my site which's hosted by winhost.com.

I am using the following code to connect to the database, which I figured out for myself:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(
        "My ConnectionString Info is in here.");
    scon.Open();
    MessageBox.Show(scon.Database);
    cd = true;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message + "\n" + exception.StackTrace);
}
```

And it connects to the database perfectly everytime. So, what I anm having trouble doing is (My database on the winhost servers is blank.) adding rows and columns to it, so i can add info later... I would like to use LINQ for this.

I have seen so many tuts online but they all seem so geared towards using a local database and then uploading it! Or using a service! But all I want to do is simply establish a connection, and send a command, something like so:

- Establish Connection with Remote SQL
  Server.
- Add Rows/Columns.
- Terminate Connection.

...And at a later point:

- Establish connection.
- Do a tiny search for something in Row X.
- Get value of Match in Row X.
- Terminate Connection.

I would really appreciate your help on this. I know it can be done. I know I've seen articles on this before but it was last year and I didn't need to access a database back then.

MSDN, WindowsCLient and Google have proved to be useless when trying to get the information that I require this time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to execute SQL DDL (CREATE TABLE etc) using the DataContext ExecuteCommand.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like fun. Thank you Cade. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in most applications, you rarely need to change the database's schema (in other words, its structure) programmatically.

You usually do it at design-time using tools like SQL Server Management Studio.

Winhost.com probably provides online tools through their admin-interface or software downloads to do this...

Comment: +1 In fact you're right, even the 'Basic' accounts allows "SQL Management Studio Access Allowed" Ref: http://winhost.com/windows-hosting-plans.aspx With SQL Server Express Mgmt Studio author could directly use db http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&displaylang=en

Comment: You are spot on; Though SQL Management Studio does not let me connect to my winhost account. BUT, the Import & Export tool that comes with it DOES. I just don't think that they are *completely* compatible with Winhost. (Winhost is great by the way.).